# How to access your guest OS folders (ubuntu) from the host OS (windows 7)?

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, shared-folders, vmware-player

I am running VMWare Player. My host machine is running Windows 7 and the guest is Ubuntu 14.04. I want to specifically access my `~/Documents` Ubuntu folder from the Host OS (Windows 7).

I know how to share a Windows folder so that Ubuntu can see the contents. I want to go the other way. How can I do this?

Comment: I does makes sense and then it doesn't. Your question is quite clear and goes to the point without adding "noise" so we thank you for that. Why you need such settings makes less sense though. That said, it should be possible to share the folder you want to the network (depending on network settings in VMware) and then it'll be visible in the host just like any other network share.

Comment: I do something very similar in reverse (Win 10 guest) and have found that for me, creating a shared directory on the host that I can access from the guest has worked quite well.

Comment: Thanks MichaelBay and Charles for your response. I thought of creating a shared directory but the issue is that you can't create any symbolic links in the /mnt/hgfs/<shared-directory>.  So instead I have been using ~/Documents folder but now need to figure out how to share it with my host machine.